# OPC Server to MySQL database

Tags: javascript, c#, c, plc

Can someone suggest me few ways to connect and map OPC server data to a SQL database? I am really new to this OPC server and i am looking for a way or a web service method to map the OPC server to a SQL database. Any kind of suggestions for a start would be really appreciated. I did research on this topic and all i could come up with are few licensed tools to do the job.

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this yourself then most likely the best approach is to write a client to read the 
required tags from the OPC Server. You are essentially writing your own OPC Client here with some 
extra code to store tags to an SQL database (and maybe a UI)

Some source code to look at:

http://www.opcconnect.com/source.php#freesource
http://support.automation.siemens.com/WW/llisapi.dll?func=cslib.csinfo&lang=en&objid=21447513&caller=view
https://fistfulofbytes.com/opc-sample-code
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/490072/DA-OPC-Wrapper-DLL-and-Client-Example

If I was doing it I would follow this example - C# is simpler then C/C++ and the source code contains the libraries you need!

http://mestaa.blogspot.it/search/label/OPC%20Client

You might want to consider OPC-DA, OPC-UA..

http://blog.matrikonopc.com/index.php/is-opc-ua-as-simple-as-opc-da/
https://accelconf.web.cern.ch/accelconf/icalepcs2011/papers/mopms025.pdf

Comment: It is a really nice comment,but I'm a little bit confused because I'm new in this field. In which platform should I program? is there any complete code for it? I just program in PLC ; 0 and 1 ;and need some help.
Thanks

Comment: C# on Windows- the mesta link has complete code (you will just have  to swap for you own server tags) - there is a download link on the bottom of the page

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest going for the Advosol library as it is a breeze to set up and get started.I have tried the paid Advosol client and I liked it.You would still have to build the entire OPC to SQL logic yourself using .net. 
If you can switch to python, OpenOPC is a very easy,free and quick alternative. The OPenOPC tool however has a memory leak that needs to be circumvented by regularly restarting of a gateway service.

[http://openopc.sourceforge.net/][1]

Comment: What does'nt work for you?If it is openOPC that doesnt work, you are probably lacking some some of the libraries like pythoncom. Install pywin32 and you can get going with openOPC.

Answer (score 0):

I don't work for, nor am I affiliated with the folks over at SoftwareToolbox, but they have an off-the shelf solution for this that I have had quite a bit of luck using. It's called Cogent Datahub, you can find it here: [Cogent Datahub](http://www.softwaretoolbox.com/cogentdatahub/)